# Teradata : Consecutive sum of columns starting from the current record and compare the result with a different column

Tags: sql, loops, teradata

Source Records:

| Product_id | Date | Qty1 | Qty2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXX | 22-12-2021 | 1000 | 250 |
| XXXX | 23-12-2021 | 200 | 50 |
| XXXX | 24-12-2021 | 1400 | 400 |
| XXXX | 25-12-2021 | 300 | 900 |
| XXXX | 26-12-2021 | 1800 | 600 |
| XXXX | 27-12-2021 | 900 | 450 |
| YYYY | 22-12-2021 | 30 | 350 |
| YYYY | 23-12-2021 | 10 | 20 |
| YYYY | 24-12-2021 | 70 | 10 |
| YYYY | 25-12-2021 | 80 | 80 |

For each product_id, date, Qty1
I would like to compare Qty1 to sum of consecutive Qty2 when it reaches to Qty1 < sum(Qty2),
count the no. Qty2's - 1 to populate the column "Qty Available for Days".

E.g:
**Record 1 Calculation:** for Product_id XXXX, Date 12/22/2021 and Qty1 1000.
Do sum of following records of Qty2 column till it reaches the value greater than Qty1 for that record.
Qty1 lessthan Sum(Qty2)
1000 lessthan Sum(250+50+400+900)
for this record no. Qty2's required to reach Qty1 lessthan Sum(Qty1) is 4 values,
so here I would like to populate 4-1=3 in "Qty Available for Days".

**Record 2 Calculation:** for Product_id XXXX, Date 12/23/2021 and Qty1 200.
Do sum of following records of Qty2 column till it reaches the value greater than Qty1 for that record.
Qty1 lessthan Sum(Qty2)
200 lessthan Sum(50+400)
for this record no. Qty2's required to reach Qty1 lessthan Sum(Qty2) is 2 values, so here I would like to populate 2-1=1 in
"Qty Available for Days".

Desired Result:

| Product_id | Date | Qty1 | Qty2 | Qty Available for Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXX | 22-12-2021 | 1000 | 250 | 3 |
| XXXX | 23-12-2021 | 200 | 50 | 1 |
| XXXX | 24-12-2021 | 1400 | 400 | 2 |
| XXXX | 25-12-2021 | 300 | 900 | 0 |
| XXXX | 26-12-2021 | 1800 | 600 | 2 |
| XXXX | 27-12-2021 | 900 | 450 | 1 |
| YYYY | 22-12-2021 | 30 | 350 | 0 |
| YYYY | 23-12-2021 | 10 | 20 | 0 |
| YYYY | 24-12-2021 | 70 | 10 | 1 |
| YYYY | 25-12-2021 | 80 | 80 | 1 |

Any inputs to solve this in Teradata SQL will be of a great help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata, and if the former then what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The desired result is great, but we need the matching table data as well. (No images or links, just properly formatted text.)

Comment: Unclear. Why *XXXX 25-12-2021 300 900 1*, not 0? Why *YYYY 22-12-2021 30 350 4*, not 0?

Comment: Akina, Thanks for pointing it Sir. I corrected it now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am using Teradata Sir.